# Trying to get div to cover entire site in order to darken page when video plays

Tags: html, css

I have a video player on my site and im trying to get the entire site to go dark when the video plays. I've put a div to wrap all content and made sure the z-index of the video and video container where higher than the div. However it's not working like I'd hoped.

It's also screwing up the alignment of my wrapper. This is my site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html 
When I wrap everything in the Shadow div. Everything moves to the left:
[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="shadow">
<div id="wrapper">

    <a href="index.html">
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>MacroPlay Games</h1>
        </header>
    </a>

    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
            <a href="video.html"><li>Trailers</li></a>
            <button type="button" data-state="0" style="float:right">Cinema Mode</button>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="body_div">

        <div id="video_container">
            <video id="trailers" poster="poster.jpg">
                <source src="vLast.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="vLast.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <nav>
               <div id="controls" class="cAnimated cFadeInRight">
                    <div id="defaultBar">
                        <div id="progressBar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
                    <button id="vol" onclick="showSlider()">Vol</button>      
                    <button id="containSlider"> 
                                <input type="range" id="vSlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/></button>
                    <div id='containTime'><span id='timeDisplay'>0:00</span><span>/</span><span id='duration'>0:00</span></div>
                    <button id="full">Full</button>
                    <button id="mute">Mute</button>

               </div> 
               <div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight">
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb1"><img src="TbGow.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vGow')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb2"><img src="TbLast.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vLast')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb3"><img src="TbTwo.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vTwo')"/></div>
               </div>
            </nav>
        </div>



        <aside id="sidebar">
        <div id="side_events">
            <h1>News</h1>
            <ul id="events">
                <li>Half-Life 3 Release: <time>04/01/13</time></li>
                <li>Borderlands 3 Release: <time>05/29/13</time></li>
                <li>E3 2013 Starting: <time>08/11/13</time></li>
                <li>Playstation 4 Release: <time>08/31/13</time></li>
                <li>Xbox 720 Release: <time>09/01/13</time></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div id="side_trailer">
                <a href="video.html"><img src="TbGow.jpg" /></a>
            </div>

        <div id="side_advert">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/W65o9R2.jpg" alt="Blackberry's Z10" title="Blackberry's Z10" id="advert">
        </div>                     
    </aside>

    </div>

    <footer id="footer">
        &copy; Copyright  by SimKessy
    </footer>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Rules pertaining to the div (Shadow):

```
#shadow{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color: red; 
    z-index: 81;

}
#video_container{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    z-index:0;
}
#video_container video{
    width: 100%;
    /*height: auto;*/
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

My codes: http://jsfiddle.net/eXJ5q/

Comment: Alright Batman, its me again fro the other day when you had problems with your flex, ill take a look for you.

Comment: The video isn't working for me by the way?

Comment: Do you mean in JsFiddle? It won't work in JsFiddle. I don't think the site supports this. But on my live site it should: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html

Comment: Does it work there for you? If not I may have more problems then I thought :/

Comment: it does now, it wasnt earlier :S

Comment: Might have been a load issue. Sometimes you need to give it a sec or two. Also I can't get the videos from the playlist to play until you hit play first on the control bar or click the player. It's weird but not a main concern for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Add this `<div class="dim"></div>` just before this `<div id="video_container">`

Then add this css

```
.dim {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#video_container{
       z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. Now I just need to change the rules to activate this whenever a video plays, but im pretty sure I know how to do that now. Thanks again!

Comment: Use jquery for that and if you need to change the opacity of the .dim just change 0.8 to 0.5 for example, also rgba is not fully supported in all browsers http://caniuse.com

Comment: My prof won't allow JQuery (asked him yesterday). And yea I was planning on separating RGBA into background-color and opacity. Easier to manage with element.style.opacity

Comment: dont know, it might work if you replaced width:100%; height:100%; width right:0px; bottom:0px; no need to set a height and width if it is touching all 4 sides

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the shadow div as a sibling rather than a parent of the video container, and everything should work as expected. you also don't need a z-index of such a high value. It can just be 1, as long as it is a greater value than those you're trying to obscure.